# pytest plugins override each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have 2 similar plugins I wrote:

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def pyplug<ID>_fixture():
    pass
```

where `<ID>` is replaced with the number I gave the plugin, i.e. '0', '1'...

I created a setup.py for each plugin:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='pyplug<ID>',
    packages=['pyplug<ID>'],
    entry_points={'pytest11': ['pkg = pyplug<ID>.plugin']}
    )
```

and inside each package, I created another dir (same name) with plugin.py file, containing the fixture described earlier.

This is my dir tree AFTER I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` for each plugin:

```
src/
├── pyplug0
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── bdist.linux-x86_64
│   │   └── lib
│   │       └── pyplug0
│   │           └── plugin.py
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── pyplug0-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
│   ├── pyplug0
│   │   └── plugin.py
│   ├── pyplug0.egg-info
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   ├── entry_points.txt
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   └── setup.py
└── pyplug1
    ├── build
    │   ├── bdist.linux-x86_64
    │   └── lib
    │       └── pyplug1
    │           └── plugin.py
    ├── dist
    │   └── pyplug1-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
    ├── pyplug1
    │   └── plugin.py
    ├── pyplug1.egg-info
    │   ├── dependency_links.txt
    │   ├── entry_points.txt
    │   ├── PKG-INFO
    │   ├── SOURCES.txt
    │   └── top_level.txt
    └── setup.py
```

This is my pip freeze:

```
attrs==19.3.0
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
more-itertools==8.2.0
packaging==20.3
pluggy==0.13.1
py==1.8.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyplug0==0.0.0
pyplug1==0.0.0
pytest==5.4.1
pytest-html==2.1.1
pytest-metadata==1.8.0
pytest-tldr==0.2.1
six==1.14.0
wcwidth==0.1.9
zipp==3.1.0
```

and this is my test file content:

```
def test_plugin(pyplug0_fixture):
    pass

def test_plugin2(pyplug1_fixture):
    pass
```

The problem is, the plugins are not registered OK.
When I install only one (doesn't matter which) and test it, it's OK. When I install both, one is overridden by the other, which makes no sense IMO, since they have different names (for both the fixture, and the plugin)

I run py3.6.10 on Ubuntu16.04

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
Both setup.py had the same entry point:

```
entry_points={"pytest11": ["KEY = VAL"]}
```

the VAL was different, but I kept using the same KEY, so the latest always won